# English Translation of Serre's "Formes modulaires et fonctions zeta p-adiques"

Tags: reference-request, p-adic-number-theory, modular-forms

I am hoping to find a translation of Serre's work *Formes modulaires et fonctions zeta p-adiques*. So far, I have found some partial results:

- [This](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masmat/files/notes/SerrePadic.pdf) paper which contains statements of the definitions and results, but none of the proofs
- [This](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c381/c10ff09692bc82cfa4bf6e3746d075cc0e86.pdf) translation of the first chapter

If anyone happens to know of a full translation, that would be very helpful.

Comment: If you are reading this paper, you are presumably pretty serious about studying modular forms and/or arithmetic geometry. If that is so, then at some point sooner or later you're going to need to learn to read mathematics in French, and looking around for translations is just putting off the inevitable. If you start with a reasonable knowledge of English -- which you clearly already have -- reading mathematics in French is *far* easier than reading a novel or a newspaper in French, or reading mathematics in German or Russian.